# Stack Level Too Deep error using Twilio API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stack, twilio

So I'm trying to integrate the [Twilio Programmable Video API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/rooms-resource#create-room) with my Rails application and I created a separate controller for it as such:

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class Api::V1::Coach::TwilioController < Api::V1::BaseController
  ACCOUNT_SID = ENV.fetch('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID')
  TWILIO_API_SID = ENV.fetch('TWILIO_KEY_SID')
  TWILIO_SECRET_KEY = ENV.fetch('TWILIO_SECRET_KEY')

  before_action :connect_to_twilio

  def create_room
    room = @twilio_token.video.rooms.create(
      unique_name: '12345',
      type: 'peer-to-peer',
      enable_turn: false
    ) 
    return render status:200, json: {     # This is the line indicated in the error
      success:true,
      jwt_token: @client,
      room_id: room.sid,
      room_status: room.status,
      room: room
    }
  end

   def connect_to_twilio
     @twilio_token = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_API_SID, TWILIO_SECRET_KEY)
   end
end
```

But every time I make a request to the method I get an error:

`SystemStackError (stack level too deep)`

Which seems really weird because there is no recursive call here.

I believe that the error is because of the API request. But if I make the same request again then it throws a different error that `room already exists`. So the API request is successful, maybe there is something wrong with the render but can't really put my finger on it :/

Comment: If you have the Twilio gem in your Gemfile, you don't need to require it. Try removing `require 'twilio-ruby'` from the top.

Comment: @miligraf I'm still getting the same error. It seems to be generating on the line of return render. So I think it's because of the code on the line before it

Comment: Is it possible that JSON serializing the `room` object is causing the issue? Also, you are using a `@client` variable that I can't see being defined in your code here. Perhaps one of those two ideas is causing this.